# How to interact with HTTP Session in a Spring JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, web-services, spring, jax-ws

I'm porting a legacy web service from running in JBoss, to running in Jetty with Spring.

Here's my web service class:

```
@WebService( serviceName = "Authentication" )
public class AuthenticationWebService
{
    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    public boolean authenticate( @WebParam( name = "clientRef" ) final String clientRef, @WebParam( name = "username" ) final String username, @WebParam( name = "password" ) final String password )
    {
         ... DO THE ACTUAL LOGIN - DB CALLS ETC

         // finally, store the username in the httpsession
         final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getMessageContext().get( MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST );
         final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute( "FIELD_USERNAME", username );
    }
}
```

To expose the service, my Spring xml looks like this:

```
    <bean id="wsExporter" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleHttpServerJaxWsServiceExporter">
        <property name="basePath" value="/webServices/"/>
        <property name="port" value="9494"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.example.AuthenticationWebService" />
```

The web service is exported in my Jetty server and I can call it (via a Junit class using JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean), however I get a nullpointerexception with request.getSession().

It looks as though "javax.xml.ws.servlet.request" is not an entry on the context.getMessageContext() map.

Have googled around and all the suggestions point at this being the correct way to get the servlet request. Is it perhaps something in the way I'm exporting the service with Spring?

Note - I can't and don't really want to be changing the behaviour of this legacy service in setting/reading values from the http session, but I'd be interested on other ways web services could do this.

Answer (score 0):

By default sessions are not maintained by jaxws.  Add this line prior to getting the session.

```
context.getMessageContext().put(javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true)
```

Comment: Why would this be required? WebServiceContext is provided, but context.getMessageContext().get( MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST ) returns null.

Comment: I've tried that but it makes no difference: context.getMessageContext().get("javax.xml.ws.servlet.request") still returns null so I cannot get the http session from it.